# how to save a file in MVC4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an MVC 4 application.  In my action method I am creating a pdf and it returns me the binary of it.
How can I save it to a file on the server?

```
 var  pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("Cruise1_option1", new { emailId = emailId }) { FileName = "Test.pdf", PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4 };
 //convert the return file to binary
 var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
```

how do i use the binary to save it into a file?

Thanks

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/RelativePath"),binary);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in the .NET Framework:

In your case:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("filenameForServer.pdf", binary);
```

You are new to StackOverflow, press the Tick button to mark accepted answer if this answered your question.